# Finding historical mean and using it as a threshold

Tags: statistical-significance, anomaly-detection, threshold

Using this data:

```
         USER   MEDIA DD_MM          SCORES
0         4       w  02/11          9737662
1         4       k  03/11         11691966
2         4       a  02/11          5140069
3         4       w  03/11         10165111
4         4       w  01/11          8962654
5         4       k  02/11         10112785
6         4       a  03/11          5661891
7         4       a  01/11          4942428
8         4       k  01/11         12246323
0         5       a  03/11           314034
1         5       w  01/11         16071400
2         5       k  03/11         16767571
3         5       k  01/11         20256912
4         5       k  02/11         15766468
5         5       w  02/11         18605524
6         5       w  03/11         20559416
7         5       a  02/11           260323
8         5       a  01/11           287743
0         8       w  03/11          2155365
```

I want to predict whether new information that comes in is  anomalous  or not. How can I set a threshold using an historical data (see below)? For instance, using the data below,  I want to raise an alarm new data comes  such as this comes in.

```
user =4, media = k, scores = 500
```

This should be classified as an anomaly. My approach is  to find the historical daily mean for user and media and then take two standard deviations (+/-) away from the mean. However, the resultant min_threshold is always negative. That means the dataset with the score of 500 is not classified as an anomaly.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Thresholds based on mean and standard deviation are reasonable if you know that your data is approximately normally distributed. While there are hypothesis tests for normality, these might not yield useful results for outlier detection, because you are interested in the variable range with very low probabilities, i.e. the long tails of the distribution. If you have many data points, you can visually check it with the R function *density* and compare it with the normal distribution, e.g. (assuming that *x* is the data):

```
plot(density(x))
lines(dnorm(seq(min(x),max(x),by=(max(x)-min(x))/500), mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x), col="red")
```

In any case, you can try a non-parametric approach by defining your thresholds on quantiles of the empirical distribution function as follows:

```
F.emp <- ecdf(x)
quantile(F.emp, c(0.01, 0.99))
```

The same thresholds could be obtained by directly computing the quantiles from the data, but using the empirical CDF has the advantage that you can also compute a (one-sided) p-value for your test value *y*:

```
m <- median(x)
if (y < m) {
  p <- F.emp(y)
} else {
  p <- 1 - F.emp(y)
}
```

In more than one dimension, the same apporach is possible on basis of a distance statistics. Here is a technical report, in which I have described the method and applied it to OCR error detection:

> Dalitz: "[Reject Options and Confidence Measures for kNN Classifiers.](https://lionel.kr.hsnr.de/%7Edalitz/data/publications/sr09-knn-rejection.pdf)" In C. Dalitz (Ed.): "Document Image Analysis with the Gamera Framework." Schriftenreihe des Fachbereichs Elektrotechnik und Informatik, Hochschule Niederrhein, vol. 8, pp. 16-38, Shaker Verlag (2009)